# Read a data from a csv and write in another csv using php

Tags: php, csv, oop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BYFs.png)  1) first csv data
create student mark sheet

```
    put 10 records like this


    header - studentno  sub1 sub2 sub3 sub4

               1        34   56   76   34
               2        54   65   87   45

2) second csv

    header - studentno  sub1 sub2 sub3 sub4  total  percentage grade
                1        34   56   76   34
                2        54   65   87   45

-> marks are out of 100
-> inside total column  - set total of all subject
-> percentage - set percentage of all marks
-> grade - assign grade as per percentage
           
            if up 80 percentage then set A
            if up 60 percentage then set B
            if up 40 percentage then set C
            if down of 40% then set FAIL
```

I have created csv file in one php file but I don't know how to edit in second file I don't know how to do it.